# ForeignKey using child inherited classes

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I want a model to accept child classes from a base, abstract class. Is it possible? Best way to do it?

```
class BaseClass(models.Model):  
    class Meta:  
        abstract = True  

class A(BaseClass):  
    ...

class B(BaseClass):  
    ...

class C(BaseClass):  
    ...

class Test(models.Model):  
    base = models.ForeignKey(BaseClass)

test_inst = Test.objects.get(something=something)
b_inst = B.objects.create()
test_inst.base = b_inst
test_inst.save()
```

Also, if the above is possible. Is it then possible to know what type the class was? In this example, the base in the class Test would have to know it's of class B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An abstract class has no backing store, which means that it does not have a PK, which means that you cannot have a relation to it. Use a [generic foreign key](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) instead.